# SSH terminal hangs (tty_ldisc_hangup)

Tags: ssh

The SSH console is timing out and I'm not able to execute any commands.

I've noticed that I can execute commands remotely but when I try to allocate TTY it hangs:

**Works:**

```
$ ssh root@example.com "uname -a"
Linux example.com 2.6.32-504.el6.x86_64 #1 SMP Tue Sep 16 01:56:35 EDT 2014 x86_64 x86_64 x86_64 GNU/Linux
```

**Hangs:**

```
$ ssh -t root@example.com "uname -a"
$ ssh root@example.com "dmesg"
tty_ldisc_hangup: waiting (sshd) for pts1 took too long, but we keep waiting...
```

- OS: RHEL 6.6
- Kernel: kernel-2.6.32-504.el6.x86_64

Comment: Since you can execute commands, it would help a lot if you'd use that to look at the sshd log file.

Comment: I've checked the SSHD log and I don't see any specific errors that could be related to this issue.

Comment: HTF: Check `ssh -t $server frgep -e 'sshd[' /var/log/auth.log` / @JennyD

Comment: Which file to look at will depend on how the server is configured. It may be `/var/log/secure`, or `/var/log/auth.log`. Also `/var/log/syslog` and/or `/var/log/messages` may be interesting.

Comment: @HTF One thing you can try in order to get a console is to login and run an X-based terminal program. E.g. `ssh -t root@example.com xterm` (or `gnome-terminal`, or `urxvt`, or whatever terminal program you may have.) Once you've got a terminal going you can troubleshoot things easier.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It looks like the problem was related to `hpsa module` shipped with kernel `kernel-2.6.32-504.el6.x86_64`.

Comment: What was the problem and how did you solve it?

Comment: More info on hpsa module @ http://stackoverflow.com/questions/26628274/kernel-hanging-the-tty-subsystem